# Reading and calculation using csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python and pardon me if this question might sound silly -

I have csv file that has 2 columns - `Value and Timestamp`. I'm trying to write a code that would take 2 paramenters - `start_date` and `end_date` and traverse the csv file to obtain all the values between those 2 dates and print the sum of `Value`

Below is my code. I'm trying to read and store the values in a list.

```
f_in = open('Users2.csv').readlines()
Value1 = []
Created = []
for i in range(1, len(f_in)):
    Value, created_date = f_in[i].split(',')
    Value1.append(Value)
    Created.append(created_date)

print Value1
print Created
```

My csv has the following format

```
10  2010-02-12 23:31:40
20  2010-10-02 23:28:11
40  2011-03-12 23:39:40
10  2013-09-10 23:29:34
420 2013-11-19 23:26:17
122 2014-01-01 23:41:51
```

When I run my code - `File1.py` as below

```
File1.py 2010-01-01 2011-03-31
```

The output should be `70`

I'm running into the following issues -

1. The data in csv is in timestamp (created_date), but the parameter passed should be date and I need to convert and get the data between those 2 dates regardless of time.
2. Once I have it in list - as described above - how do I proceed to do my calculation considering the condition in point-1

Comment: Please provide some example of your csv data and the parameter of your function.

Comment: Have you tried pandas to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))
start_date = 10
end_data = 30

times = [' '.join(i) for i in data if int(i[0]) in range(start_date, end_date)]
```

Comment: I really doubt if putting whole `.csv` file into memory is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that dates are in timestamp, you can compare them like strings. By realizing that, what you want to achieve (sum the `value`s if `created` is between `start_date` and `end_date`) can be done like this:

```
def sum_values(start_date, end_date):
    sum = 0
    with open('Users2.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            value, created = line.split(' ', 1)
            if created > start_date && created < end_date:
                sum += int(value)
    return sum
```

`str.split(' ', 1)` will split on `' '` but will stop splitting after 1 split has been done. `start_date` and `end_date` must be in format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` which I assume they are, cause they are in timestamp format. Just mind it.

Comment: @Pythonist You do know that you can compare strings alphabetically like `'a' < 'b'` returns `True`??? Maybe try running it first?? `'2017-01-01 20:00:00' < '2017-01-01 20:00:01'` results in `True`

Comment: You simply can't add `str` to an `int`, as you did in `sum += value`. Maybe try running it first?

Comment: Oh that, yep, i forgot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your file size, but you may consider putting values from `csv` file, into some database, and then query your results.

`csv` module has `DictReader` which allows you to predefine your column names, it greatly improves readability, specially while working on really big files.

```
from datetime import datetime

COLUMN_NAMES = ['value', 'timestamp']


def sum_values(start_date, end_date):
    sum = 0

    with open('Users2.csv', mode='r') as csvfile:
        table = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=COLUMN_NAMES)
        for row in table:
            if row['timestamp'] >= min_date and row['timestamp'] <= max_date:
                sum += int(row['value'])
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using `pandas`, try this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = 'Users2.csv'
>>>
>>> dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> df = pd.read_csv(data, names=['value', 'date'], parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse)

>>> result = df['value'][(df['date'] > '2010-01-01') &
...                      (df['date'] < '2011-03-31')
...                 ].sum()
>>> result
70
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the following error
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: Make sure the value and dates are in separate columns in the `Users2.csv` or use the appropriate separator e.g. `,` or `\t`